# How to call an image with local path from JSON in JS?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I have a JSON on say www.website.com/cardata that contains the image as following:

```
"image": "data/models/peugeot-2008-138twf_600X400_.jpg
```

When calling the image within the code how do I specify that this image is in fact something like:

```
website.com/data/models/peugeot-2008-138twf_600X400_.jpg?
```

Thanks

Comment: You should prefix your image with a `/` otherwise it won't always work. For example it would work on `x.html` but not `y/z.html` due to the fact that you are telling it to look in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it in front of the string: (If I got you right)

```
yourImageElement.src = 'website.com/' + jsonObject.image
```